# How to prove that the random variables $X$ and $X^2$ are not independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Given that the probability density function of random variable $X$ is given by
$$f(X)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac12,&\text{for} -1\le x\le1\\0,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

I tried it using expectations but it turned out that $\Bbb E(X^3)=\Bbb E(X)\Bbb E(X^2)$.
What should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $Y$ are also independent for any measurable function $f$. In particular this is true for $f(x)=x^{2}$ so independence  of $X$ and $X^{2}$ implies that $X^{2}$ is independent of itself. But that implies that $X^{2}$ is  a constant, which is obviously not true.

Alternatively note that $P(|X|\leq \frac 1 2, X^{2} \leq \frac 1 4)=\frac  1 2$ and $P(|X|\leq \frac 1 2)P( X^{2}\leq \frac 1 4)=\frac  12 \frac 1 2 =\frac 1  4$ so $P(|X|\leq \frac 1 2, X^{2} \leq \frac 1 4) \neq P(|X|\leq \frac 1 2)P( X^{2}\leq \frac 1 4)$. For independence of $X$ and $X^{2}$ we require $P(X \in A, X^{2}\in B)=P(X \in A)P( X^{2}\in B)$ for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$. Taking $A=(-\frac  1 2, \frac  1 2),B=(-\frac  1 4, \frac  1 4)$ we get a  contradiction.

Comment: Nice discussion (+1). I couldn't resist showing an example by simulation and graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Simulation illustrates the result: The distribution in
question is $\mathsf{Unif}(-1,1).$

```
abline(v=mean(y2), col="green2")
set.seed(2020)
x = runif(10^5, -1, 1)
cor(x, x^2)
[1] -0.002717596
```

This suggests that random variables $X$ and $X^2$ are
uncorrelated, which is also obvious from symmetry and
easily to prove analytically using the definition of
$Cov(X, X^2),$ as you have discovered. However (except for jointly *normal* random variables) lack of correlation does not imply independence.

The plot below shows a strong functional relationship
that is nonlinear. [The 100,000 plotting points are so
close together that they appear to make a parabola in the plot.]

```
plot(x, x^2, pch=".")
 abline(v = c(-.5,.5), col="blue")
 abline(h = 4/9. col="green")
```

[image]

From the graph, independence fails because
$$P(-.5 \le X \le .5) = 0.5 > 0\;\;\mathrm{and}\;\;P(X^2 > 4/9) = 1/3>0,$$
but the intersection of these events (the upper-central rectangle bounded by blue and green
lines) has probability $0.$